# Would like to know how these works (swap function and sort function in C)

Tags: c

I'm fairly new to C and I would like to understand these two functions:

Swap function:

```
void swap(int a, int b) {
    int temp=a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;

    printf("In swap\n");
    printf("a: %d\n", a);
    printf("b: %d\n", b);
}
```

Usage:

```
int a=5, b=7;
swap(a, b);
```

Sort function:

```
void sort(int values[], int n)
{
    for (int i=1; i < n; i++) {
        int element=values[i];
        int j=i;
        while ((j > 0) && (values[j-1] > element)) {
            values[j]=values[j - 1];
            j--;
            values[j]=element;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Usage:

```
int array={9, 1, 8, 5, 3, 2, 5};
int size=7;
sort(array, size);
```

My question is, why does the swap function didn't return with the values swapped? If the values passed to the swap function takes different addresses (I guess) so that the values outside the function aren't swapped, then why does the sort function return the array sorted? Does this mean that the values in the array passed to the sort function has the same addresses?

Comment: If you want difference swap two normal integer variable and check the result. From that you can understand what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already understood, C has "call by value", so what is sent to the swap function are copies of the original values, and it's just those copies that are swapped.

Arrays are a bit special in C. In most cases, when you write the name of an array in a C program, it gets converted to a pointer to its first element. So when you (try to) pass an array to a function, what is actually sent to the function is a pointer to the first element, so any changes in your sort function will be done on the original copy.

Comment: Thanks! So that's what happens :)

Comment: Addition: In theory, everything in C is copied when passed to a function. But with the array, just the address is copied, not each value. You could change the address within the function, but this changes will be lost. However, the original and copied addresses refer to the same memory location, where your actual array content is...

Comment: Addition on top of @deviantfan There is no syntax to bind an array type to a function parameter. So it is not that a function taking an array will only take a pointer to the first element, but that the function takes a pointer in the first place. You could pass it a pointer to a single element and it would happily compile. So, the function's parameter is a pointer, and the array decays to pointer, thereby matching the signature.

Answer (score 1):

Your swap function will do nothing since you're passing stuff by value and not returning it anywhere.

```
void swap(int a, int b) {
    int temp=a;
    a=b; // This is local to the function
    b=temp; // Ditto

    printf("In swap\n");
    printf("a: %d\n", a);
    printf("b: %d\n", b);
}
```

The sort function works because of **array decaying**. When you're calling your function like

```
int array[] = { 9, 1, 8, 5, 3, 2, 5 };
int size = 7;
sort(array, size);
```

the array parameter `int values[]` has its usage equivalent as if it were declared and passed as `int* pointer_to_the_first_element_of_the_array` and thus every usage will actually modify the original array and not a local copy.

More information on [array decaying here](http://boredzo.org/pointers/#arrays).

Comment: Yes, the swap function won't do anything unless the values passed are pointers. Thanks anyway.